# Surge protector behaving strangely

Tags: motherboard, power, cmos, surge-protection, master

I just bought [this surge protector](https://www.brennenstuhl.com/en-DE/products/extension-leads/secure-tec-19.500a-automatic-extension-socket-with-surge-protection-8-way-anthracite-3m-h05vv-f-3g1-5-1xmaster-5xslave-2xpermanent) which has the [master/slave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master/slave_(technology)), so that it disables some plugs (2 monitors and 2 speakers) when I turn off my PC. Everything is working fine except for one thing: around 7AM (always at the same time in the morning) it starts turning on and off the plugs at an interval of 1 second or so.

This is the third time this happens and I have to wake up to turn the main switch off, since the devices connected to it might get seriously damaged from this behavior. When I turn the surge protector back on after an hour or so everything is back to normal. I also tried to set the [Threshold level switch](https://www.brennenstuhl.com/index.php?module=explorer&index%5Bexplorer%5D%5Baction%5D=download&index%5Bexplorer%5D%5Bfile%5D=shop_articles/en-DE/pdf/4007123611867_1159490936_1_xx_data_sheet.pdf) *(link to the surge protector manual)* to the maximum level *(80 W)*, so that a large amount of power has to be drawn from the master plug to power the slaves on, but nothing has changed.

I was about to return the product, but then I thought "how is it possible for a defective product to always starts misbehaving at the exact same time?". So, can the problem be PC-related? Something like it absorbing energy at 7AM to keep the [CMOS battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory#CMOS_battery) charged... And how to prevent this behavior? Please don't just tell me to "turn the surge protector off at night".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this were mine and new (as it is) I would contact the manufacturer support people, ask for help, and possibly return the device

Comment: As you state, likely the PC *is* starting up at 7 AM... but likely, not because of the battery -- that would occur at random times. Look for wake-on-LAN, or scheduled task (cron jobs) that start at 7 AM (or equivalent to 7 AM Zulu time).

Comment: @John thanks for your answer... I bought it at a mall so it's not that easy, that's why I would prefer to understand the root cause first

Comment: @DrMoishePippik let me take a look at the task scheduler and I'll let you know. Anyway, the PC does not startup at all, it just suddenly starts absorbing energy.

Comment: For a test, shut off and disconnect the surge protector temporarily. Does the computer operate normally now?  If so it is most likely a problem with the surge protector.

Comment: @John the computer already operates normally. It does not startup at all... What it does (or at least it may do) is absorbing energy from the surge protector at 7AM.

Comment: Also, use *Hibernate*, rather than *Sleep*, because *Sleep* always uses a trickle of energy.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I always completely turn off my pc at night

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by changing my surge protector with a brand new one.